# Stuck reading string from file

Tags: java, minecraft

I am trying to match a String in a text file with one from user input.  I am able to find and display it using a while loop with `if (String.valueOf(str).toLowerCase().contains(u))`,
but say I have a line with test and the next line with test3 it will print both lines.  What I need it to do is search for just test and print the line it is on without printing test3 also.

*Edit* Sorry I'm not very good at describing this.  The problem is this:
I have a class that writes an array using `StringBuilder()` to a text file like so.

[Date and Time] John Test Dog

[Date and Time] Mary Test3 Moo

So I get user input and lets say it is test. I need to make the below reader search all the lines in the file for only "test" and send the entire line it is  on back.  But when I do it with what I currently have it will send back the line for "test" and "test3".  Also the position for "test" will always be the same in the string.

Sorry for being so vague I am still very new to this.

Here is my reader atm:

```
Reader reader = new FileReader("EzRegion.txt");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(reader);

while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) 
{
    if (String.valueOf(str).toLowerCase().contains(u)) 
    {
        sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.YELLOW + str);
    }
}
```

Comment: please edit and add more info to problem or your wasting time

Comment: You have to ignore 'test3'. Why? On what basis? What rule applies? What else do you have to ignore?

Answer (score 2):

You say you have many elements (tokens) to match. So you have "bob", "John" etc and I guess they can be in any order in the file but all should be there on same line.

Make a [java.util.StringTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) and a flag to ensure all tokens match. in the loop for tokens match using equals

```
 StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str);
 boolean matchFlag = true;
 while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
    String s3 = st.nextToken().toLowerCase();
    String match = u.trim().toLowerCase();
    if(!u.equals(s3)){
            matchFlag = false;
            //logger
 }
```

Use

```
str.toLowerCase().equals(u)
```

No need to call String.valueOf as you already have a string. also your lower case so test and Test will match if u is on lowercase and str is 'Test' or 'TEST' ...

Use
    str.equals(u)

To match case sensitive.

If you want to remove spaces then use trim as in

```
str.trim()
```

OR

```
str.trim().toLowerCase()
```

Note if you going to use the trimmed or lower case string more than once its a good idea to assign the value to a new variable and use the new variable.

Like

```
String sTrmed = str.trim();
if(sTrmed.equals(u))   { //....
```

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to include that (u) is a single element such as test in a line with other strings such as bob john test moo so .equals() won't work as the entire line will not match.

Answer (score 1):

You could use regular expressions. For example using code block like this:

```
//str (e.g. "[Date and Time] John Test3 Dog")
String u = "test"; //whatever you are looking for
String REGEX = "\\b"+t.toLowerCase()+"\\b" ; //look for the exact word
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(REGEX);
Matcher m = p.matcher(str.toLowerCase());
if (m.find()) //if you are after multiple instances, then it needs to be replaced by a while-loop
{
    //your code here:
    System.out.println("start(): " + m.start());
    System.out.println("end(): " + m.end());

    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.YELLOW + str);
}
else
    System.out.println("No match found");
```

I think, you need something like this to go into your while-loop block.